# Maven commons-io information does not match signer information

Tags: maven, maven-3, java-ee-7, apache-commons-io

i am facing a possible conflict in my project with the commons-io on which some of my dependency depend.

In detail, with my current maven dependency setup, i am receiving the following exception which is thrown in the **core** module:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

So i checked the dependency tree of my project. Below is the output.

**Note**: The **Web Application** module has a dependency on the  **Core** module, while the **Core** module has a dependency on **ESB common** module

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] tempProject
[INFO] tempProject and ESB common classes
[INFO] tempProject Core
[INFO] tempProject Web Application
[INFO] tempProject EAR
[INFO] tempProject Jobs
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tempProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ tempProject ---
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tempProject and ESB common classes 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ tempProject-lib ---
[INFO] mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-lib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws-mar:pom:1.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-saaj:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-metadata:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tempProject Core 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ tempProject-core ---
[INFO] mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-core:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-lib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws-mar:pom:1.5:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-saaj:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-metadata:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tempProject Web Application 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7.jbossorg-1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ tempProject-web ---
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7.jbossorg-1
[INFO] mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-lib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws-mar:pom:1.5:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-saaj:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO] |     |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-metadata:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO] |     |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] \- net.fckeditor:java-core:jar:2.5:runtime
[INFO]    \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:runtime - version managed from 1.3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tempProject EAR 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ tempProject-ear ---
[INFO] mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-ear:ear:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-core:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-lib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]       |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       \- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws-mar:pom:1.5:compile
[INFO]          +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]          |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-saaj:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]          |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]          |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-metadata:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]          |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]          |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]          \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tempProject Jobs 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ tempProject-jobs ---
[INFO] mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-jobs:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO]    \- mypackage.tempProject:tempProject-lib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO]       +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO]       |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO]       +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO]       |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       \- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws-mar:pom:1.5:provided
[INFO]          +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO]          |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-saaj:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO]          |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]          |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-metadata:jar:1.5:provided
[INFO]          |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]          |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]          \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided - version managed from 1.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] tempProject .............................................. SUCCESS [  6.568 s]
[INFO] tempProject and ESB common classes ....................... SUCCESS [  1.903 s]
[INFO] tempProject Core ......................................... SUCCESS [ 16.499 s]
[INFO] tempProject Web Application .............................. SUCCESS [  7.391 s]
[INFO] tempProject EAR .......................................... SUCCESS [  4.558 s]
[INFO] tempProject Jobs ......................................... SUCCESS [  3.423 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 41.705 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-12T10:45:02+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/516M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1) My first step was to exclude from all the ESB common dependencies the commons-io , which is not used anyway in this module. Then i included the core module the commons-io 2.4 as provided (using Wildlfly 10). That did not fix the problem.

2) Second try was to add the following in my parent pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

With that change i was unable to deploy the application, while i was getting the following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils

3) I tried in the dependencyManagement as shown in (2) to add type: pom and scope: import. Again i could not deploy my project.

Any suggestions?

**Note**: Wildfly 10 comes with commons-io 2.4.

Comment: So you have to define the dependency as scope provided but not in dependencyManagement.

Comment: Finally resolved the issue by removing completely everything that had to do with commons-io.